# When can a function be represented by a power series?

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

I saw a theorem:

> If $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ can be represented by a power series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n(x-a)^n$, then $\displaystyle c_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}$ for all $n=0,1,2,\ldots$.

But, I also saw an example that the power series $f(x)=\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\cdot5^n}(x-3)^n$ has a convergence interval $[-2,8)$. The question now comes: this function $f$ can be represented by a power series, but its coefficient $c_n$ seems not of the form like the theorem says, because it doesn't even have a factorial term. What's wrong?

Comment: When you repeatedly differentiate a power you get a factorial, which cancels out with the factorial in the bottom of the fraction.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{n \cdot 5^n} = \frac{\frac{n!}{n \cdot 5^n}}{n!}$$

Comment: The problem is that one does not know what is $f^{(n)}(a)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is wrong.  Notice that

$$c_n=\frac1{n\times5^n}=\frac{f^{(n)}(3)}{n!}$$

Thus, it just so happens that for this particular function,

$$f^{(n)}(3)=\frac{(n-1)!}{5^n}$$

so the factorials cancel out.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: For $f^{(n)}(a)=(n-1)!/5^n$ the coefficient $c_n=f^{(n)}(a)/n!=\frac{1}{5^n n}$

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is also "no" factorial term in
$$
\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots,\quad |x|<1.
$$

The point is that there could be *cancellation* in the fraction
$$
\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}.
$$